# MVVMCross View Model Prepare method not called when Hot Reload (ing) XAML changes

Tags: visual-studio, mvvmcross, hot-reload

I started using MVVMCross several weeks ago and so far I love it, but I've noticed that whenever I'm working on the UI and making changes in the XAML and pressing save which activates the Hot Reload in Visual Studio 2019, I'm getting Null Reference Exceptions.

This is down to the fact that the MVVMCross' Prepare method is not getting called. According to their doc's this method is used to pass a parameter to the VM which can then be used throughout the VM.

```
    public override void Prepare(MyClass param)
    {
        MyClass = param;
    }

    public override Task Initialize()
    {
        MyClass.DoSomething();
        return base.Initialize();
    }
```

So this is the basic usage (I think). However when I Hot Reload the XAML changes Prepare isn't called but Initialize is, which causes the Exception.

Is this a bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare in normal cases will only be called when calling NavigationService.Navigate.

What Hot Reload actually does is unclear. This use case is currently not officially supported by MvvmCross.